# How I can split the directory path to the 5 level in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to parse directory to 5 Level in SQL server with string function.

```
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123\456\123\ABD
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156\456\123\ABD\123\565
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179\456\123\ABD\123\565\ZYX
```

I need a below result.

```
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123\
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156\
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179\
```

Comment: Please suggest me any function which I can used in SQL server.

Comment: This is going to be tough to swing without regex support (which sadly SQL Server does not really ship with...yet).  You might want to handle this in your application layer.

Comment: May be it's possible with the query.

Comment: so these records are in a column

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to create a database function, you can achieve your required data.

**Create Function:**

```
USE [your_database_name];
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[find_nth_char_position]
(@TargetStr   VARCHAR(8000), 
 @SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000), 
 @Occurrence  INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @pos INT, @counter INT, @ret INT;
         SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr);
         SET @counter = 1;
         IF @Occurrence = 1
             SET @ret = @pos;
             ELSE
             BEGIN
                 WHILE(@counter < @Occurrence)
                     BEGIN
                        IF CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr, @pos + 1) = 0
                        BEGIN
                             RETURN(0)
                        END

                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                             SELECT @ret = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr, @pos + 1);
                             SET @counter = @counter + 1;
                             SET @pos = @ret;
                        END
         END;
         END;
         RETURN(@ret);
     END;
GO
```

This above function will return the Nth position of a character in the provided string. As you required the PATH till level 5, I have find the 6th position of character "\" and keep string up to that position using SUBSTRING method.

**Select Statement:**

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING
(
    <db column name>,
    1,
    CASE
        WHEN [dbo].[find_nth_char_position]('\',<db column name>,6) = 0 THEN LEN(<db column name>) 
        ELSE [dbo].[find_nth_char_position]('\',<db column name>,6)
    END
)
FROM <your_table>
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e74854192b82113f357ca7cd7aff173)

Comment: MkRabbani ...It's working but problem is when level is only have 3 or level then it's not given in output.

Comment: Wait a min.. changing the logic.

Comment: @PragneshPrajapati can you please check now?

Comment: It's giving error....Argument data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for argument 3 of substring function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @PragneshPrajapati. Updated both function definition and select script. Please try after altering your function accordingly.

Comment: :( can you please check this fiddle output - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e74854192b82113f357ca7cd7aff173

Comment: Its working as expected at my place and in the dbfiddle as well. @PragneshPrajapati

Answer (score 1):

You may try with the following approach:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   TextData varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (TextData)
VALUES
    ('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123\456\123\ABD'),
    ('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156\456\123\ABD\123\565'),
    ('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS'),
    ('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179\456\123\ABD\123\565\ZYX')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Part1, Part2, Part3, Part4, Part5, Part6) AS TextData
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(d.TextData, '\'), CHARINDEX('\', CONCAT(d.TextData, '\'))) AS Part1, STUFF(CONCAT(d.TextData, '\'), 1, CHARINDEX('\', CONCAT(d.TextData, '\')), '') AS TextData) c1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(c1.TextData, CHARINDEX('\', c1.TextData)) AS Part2, STUFF(c1.TextData, 1, CHARINDEX('\', c1.TextData), '') AS TextData) c2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(c2.TextData, CHARINDEX('\', c2.TextData)) AS Part3, STUFF(c2.TextData, 1, CHARINDEX('\', c2.TextData), '') AS TextData) c3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(c3.TextData, CHARINDEX('\', c3.TextData)) AS Part4, STUFF(c3.TextData, 1, CHARINDEX('\', c3.TextData), '') AS TextData) c4
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(c4.TextData, CHARINDEX('\', c4.TextData)) AS Part5, STUFF(c4.TextData, 1, CHARINDEX('\', c4.TextData), '') AS TextData) c5
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(c5.TextData, CHARINDEX('\', c5.TextData)) AS Part6, STUFF(c5.TextData, 1, CHARINDEX('\', c5.TextData), '') AS TextData) c6
```

Output:

```
--------------------
TextData
--------------------
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123\
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156\
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179\
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. By using `string_split` you can convert your string into rows, then find out the top records as you needed in your code to get the desired result.

After that use `stuff` to again concatenate into single string and get your output.

```
declare @tab table ( col varchar(max) )
insert into @tab ( col)
values ( '\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123\456\123\ABD' )
,('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156\456\123\ABD\123\565')
,('\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179\456\123\ABD\123\565\ZYX')

select  stuff((select top 6 '\' + value from string_split(col, '\') for xml path('')),1,1,'')  as Result from @tab


--- by using our own created split function, if you are allowed to do so.
select  stuff((select top 6 '\' + items from Split(col, '\') for xml path('')),1,1,'')  as Result from @tab



Result
----------------
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\123
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\156
\ABC\BC\ADS\ADS\179
```

You may create your own `split` function to make sure that order will not change in parsing.

```
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(@String nvarchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(max)
-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
--     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN
-- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
-- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
IF @INDEX !=0
SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
-- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)
-- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
-- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Documentation about `STRING_SPLIT` states that _... The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string ..._.  I'm not sure that `STRING_SPLIT` is an option here.